# Replace articles.php?id=123 with /articles/123-title-of-article

Tags: php, mysql, url-rewriting

I am building a php+mysql site which will have numerous articles. I am pretty ok with html php jquery etc. I need to now what are the steps I need to take in order not have http://www.mysite.com/articles.php?id=123 but to have http://www.mysite.com/articles/123-title-of-article?
Thanks

Comment: You may prefer to use mod_rewrite for this, rather than PHP.

Comment: Since this is done in the webserver, you may wanna add your webserver software in case it's not apache.

Comment: mod_rewrite can translate `/123-title-of-article` to `/articles.php?id=123`; it will NOT generate pretty links for you. This, you have to do in PHP.

Comment: Thanks to all who replied. Valuable advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need, for instance, to store the token for each article (to optimize), like your example "`123-title-of-article`". Next step is to use `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` from Apache (if is your case).

If you will do it *only* on this articles "page folder" (`articles/`), I suggest to you make this folder valid and make the `.htaccess` inside that and redirect to `articles.php?id={POST_ID_FOUND_BY_TOKEN}`.

Take a look too on `$_SERVER["REQUEST_*"]` variables from PHP.

**See**: [this page](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite), on end of article have some examples.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this is by using mod_rewrite.
You create a .htaccess file which, behind the scene, redirects the latter request to the former.

You can read about it here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something called [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), which is an apache module.

The configuration looks like this (stolen from a client's drupal install):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule articles/(.*)$ articles.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work.